# Selenium RC is unexpectedly shutting down exactly after 10 minutes

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-rc

Any idea whats going on here? I have never faced this issue before, suddenly I had to do write an automation code for a test case which runs more than 10 minutes. And I found the server is shutting down unexpectedly right after 10 minutes.

It shows this in my log file when it shuts down:
    21:47:49,133  INFO GenericApplicationContext:1002 - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@1ef8cf3: startup date [Tue Dec 18 21:37:49 CST 2012]; root of context hierarchy

I'm using RemoteControlConfiguration & SeleniumServer in my setup.

```
 org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer
 org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteControlConfiguration
```

All test cases are running fine if its less than 10 minutes. I'm using 2.25 version.

WebDriver might resolve it, but going towards WebDriver is not feasible at this moment because of some other in-house issues. So I'm not looking into that area.

To over-confirm whether it's a time-out issue, I also run something like this:

```
waitForPageToLoad(1000*60*11)
```

Explicitly passing time to wait 11 minutes and its shutting down after 10 minutes.

Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm running my selenium test cases through junit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can also run on different port with different test suites..
hope it might help you
```